# how to use javascript if else url redirect in my project

Tags: javascript

I am doing a pizza parlor 3 page mock site for my javascript project. I am trying to make it stay on the same page when the information is not present. I have a function triggered by the onClick event in my submit button that gives an alert if the radio buttons are not checked, and sets the cookies and passes them to the next page, but I want it to remain on the same page so the user can fill out the info and then submit the order. I have tried the location.reload method, as well as the url redirect. We did not go over these in class, so I could totally be writing/using them wrong. also I don't know if this has to be hosted for these to work as it is still just a file on my desktop. 
Can some one post an example of how I can achieve this? I have put my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Pizza Parlor</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="pizzaParlor.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pizzaParlor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
        var message = "";

        //SetCookie("cat","dog");
        //alert(GetCookie("cat"));

        // Here are 2 ways you could setup the javascript to handle this.
        // Lets setup our order in an Array
        /*
         * index - Description of what it holds.
         * 0 - Size of Pizza
         * 1 - Crust type
         * 2 - Type of pizza
         * 3 - Array of toppings.
         */
        var order = new Array(" "," "," ");
        var sale = new Array(0,0,0);
        var total = 0;
        var tax = 0;
        var grandtotal = 0;

        //Another way would be to create an order object.

        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        isSpecialty()
         * purpose:     Checks Pizza Type.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/03/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */
        function isSpecialty(){
        if(jquery("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() ==       "Hawiian"){
                order[3] = false;
                return true;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() == "Veggie") {
                order[3] = false;
                return true;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() == "MeatLovers") {
                order[3] = false;
                return true;
            } else {
                // Is Custom
                order[3] = true;
                return false;
            } // end if else
        } // end function isSpecialty()


        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        addSize()
         * purpose:     Checks Pizza Type.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/03/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */
        function addSize(){
            if($("input:radio[name=size]:checked").val() == "12"){
                order[0] = "12 inch pie";
            } else if($("input:radio[name=size]:checked").val() == "16"){
                order[0] = "16 inch pie";
            } else if($("input:radio[name=size]:checked").val() == "20"){
                order[0] = "20 inch pie";
            } // end if else

            if($("input:radio[name=size]:checked").val() == "12"){
                sale[0] = 10;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=size]:checked").val() == "16"){
                sale[0] = 12;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=size]:checked").val() == "20"){
                sale[0] = 14;
            } // end if else

            updateDisplay();
        } // end function addSize()


        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        addCrust()
         * purpose:     Checks Pizza Type.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/03/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */
        function addCrust(){
            if($("input:radio[name=crust]:checked").val() == "Hand-Tossed"){
                order[1] = "Hand-Tossed";
            } else if($("input:radio[name=crust]:checked").val() == "Deep Dish"){
                order[1] = "Deep Dish";
            }  // end if else

            if($("input:radio[name=crust]:checked").val() == "Hand-Tossed"){
                sale[1] = 1;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=crust]:checked").val() == "Deep Dish"){
                sale[1] = 2;
            }  // end if else

            updateDisplay();
        } // end function addCrust()


        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        addType()
         * purpose:     Adds Pizza Type: Specialty(Hawiian, Veggie, Meat Lovers) or Custom.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/03/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */
        function addType(){
            if($("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() == "Hawiian"){

                // put your code here for disabling the topping checkboxes of custom.
                // Maybe call a function which disables those Elements of the form.
                disableTop();
                order[2] = "Hawiian";
                sale[2] = 1;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() == "Veggie"){

                // put your code here for disabling the topping checkboxes of custom.
                // Maybe call a function which disables those Elements of the form.
                disableTop();
                order[2] = "Veggie";
                sale[2] = 1;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() == "MeatLovers"){

                // put your code here for disabling the topping checkboxes of custom.
                // Maybe call a function which disables those Elements of the form.
                disableTop();
                order[2] = "Meat Lovers";
                sale[2] = 2;
            } else if($("input:radio[name=custom]:checked").val() == "BuildYourOwn"){

                // put your code here for enable the topping checkboxes of custom.
                // Maybe call a function which enables those Elements of the form.
                enableTop();
                order[2] = "Build Your Own";
                sale[2] = 0;
                if ($("input:checkbox[id=top01]:checked").val() == "Pineapple"){
                  sale[2] = sale[2]+.50;
                }
                if ($("input:checkbox[id=top02]:checked").val() == "Chicken"){
                  sale[2] = sale[2]+.50;
                }
                if ($("input:checkbox[id=top03]:checked").val() == "Canadian Bacon"){
                  sale[2] = sale[2]+.50;
                }
                if ($("input:checkbox[id=top04]:checked").val() == "Sausage"){
                  sale[2] = sale[2]+.50;
                }
                if ($("input:checkbox[id=top05]:checked").val() == "Pepperoni"){
                  sale[2] = sale[2]+.50;
                }
                if ($("input:checkbox[id=top06]:checked").val() == "Tomatoes"){
                  sale[2] = sale[2]+.50;
                }
            }// end if else

            updateDisplay();
        } // end function addCrust()

        function disableTop(){
            // JavaScript
            document.getElementById('top01').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('top02').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('top03').disabled = true;

            //$('#top01').attr("disabled", true);               
            //$('#top02').attr("disabled", true);
            //$('#top03').attr("disabled", true);

            // jQuery
            $('#top04').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#top05').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#top06').attr("disabled", true);

            $('#tbltop').addClass('disabled');
        } // end function disableTop()

        function enableTop(){
            $('#top01').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#top02').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#top03').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#top04').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#top05').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#top06').attr("disabled", false);

            $('#tbltop').removeClass('disabled');
        } // end function enableTop()

        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        updateDisplay()
         * purpose:     Updates the shopping cart with any changes in order.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/03/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */
        function updateDisplay(){
            //alert("updateDisplay was called");
            //alert(order[0]);
            $('#messages').text("");
            total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i++){
                $('#messages').append(order[i] + " $" + sale[i] + "<br />");
                total = total + sale[i];                    
            } // end for loop
            tax = total*.09;
            grandtotal = total + tax;
            $('#messages').append("Subtotal $" + total + "<br /><br />");
            $('#messages').append("Tax $" + tax + "<br /><br />");
            $('#messages').append("Total $" + grandtotal + "<br /><br />");
        } // end function updateDisplay()

        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        clearDisplay()
         * purpose:     Clears the shopping cart display.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/03/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */         
        function clearDisplay(){
            $('#tbltop').removeClass('disabled');
            $('#messages').text("");

            for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i ++){
                order[i] = " ";
                sale[i] = " ";
            } // end for loop

        } // end function clearDisplay()

        //validate radio function(check to see if this is ness, if page one has a form, otherwise you will have to do this different.)
        function validateRadio(){
            if (document.shopcart.size[0].checked) return true;
            if (document.shopcart.size[1].checked) return true;
            if (document.shopcart.size[2].checked) return true;
            if (document.shopcart.crust[0].checked) return true;
            if (document.shopcart.crust[1].checked) return true;
            //if (document.shopcart.custom[0].checked) return true;
            //if (document.shopcart.custom[1].checked) return true;
            return false;

            }

        /* -----------------------------------------------------
         * name:        yumCookies()
         * purpose:     Places form data in cookies.
         * author:      Eric Collins
         * date:        03/12/2014
         * parameters:  none
         */         
        function yumCookies(){
            var pizzaSize = order[0];
            var pizzaCrust = order[1];
            var pizzaType = order[2];

            if (validateRadio() == false)
            {
                alert("Please make your pizza choice selections and try again");    
                return; 

            }
            alert("Fill out your information and submit it to finish your pizza order");
            return;

            SetCookie("pizSZ", pizzaSize);
            SetCookie("pizzaCRST", pizzaCrust);
            SetCookie("pizzaTyp", pizzaType);
            SetCookie("saleSZ", sale[0]);
            SetCookie("saleCRST", sale[1]);
            SetCookie("saleTyp", sale[2]);

            //alert(GetCookie("pizSZ"));
            //alert(GetCookie("pizzaCRST"));
            //alert(GetCookie("pizzaTyp"));

            if (validateRadio() == false)
            {
                location.reload;
            }

            }; // end function yumCookies()

    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>      
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">          
        <div id="header" class="header">
            <img src="images/pizzaParlorLogo.png" alt="LogoImage" height="100" width="150" style="float: left;" />

            <h1>Josh's Pizza Parlor</h1>

            <span style="text-align: right;">(425) 555-1212</span><br />
            <span style="text-align: right;">555 5th Ave</span><br />
            <span style="text-align: right;">Everett, WA  98203</span>              
        </div>            
        <!-- horizontal menu -->
        <div id="horizontalMenu" style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="custInfo.html">Customer Info</a>
            <a href="summary.html">Order Summary</a>
        </div>
        <!-- horizontal menu -->
        <br />
        <div id="content" class="main">
            <div id="center" class="yourOrder">

                <h2>Create your Order</h2>
                <hr />
                <form name="shopcart" action="custInfo.html" method="post">
                    <span style="color: white;">Select your pizza size:</span>
                    <input type="radio" name="size" value="12" class="pieSize" onclick="addSize()" /> 12"
                    <input type="radio" name="size" value="16" class="pieSize" onclick="addSize()" /> 16"
                    <input type="radio" name="size" value="20" class="pieSize" onclick="addSize()" /> 20"
                    <hr />
                    <span style="color: white;">Select your crust type:</span>
                    <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Hand-Tossed" onclick="addCrust()" /> Hand-tossed
                    <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Deep Dish" onclick="addCrust()" /> Deep dish
                    <hr />
                    <span  style="color: white;">Build your own:</span>
                    <input type="radio" name="custom" value="BuildYourOwn" onclick="addType()" /> Custom<br />
                    <br />
                    <table id="tbltop">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="top01" name="topping" value="Pineapple" onclick="addType()"/> Pineapple</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="top02" name="topping" value="Chicken" onclick="addType()"/> Chicken</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="top03" name="topping" value="Canadian Bacon" onclick="addType()"/> Canadian Bacon</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="top04" name="topping" value="Sausage" onclick="addType()"/> Sausage</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="top05" name="topping" value="Pepperoni" onclick="addType()"/> Pepperoni</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="top06" name="topping" value="Tomatoes" onclick="addType()"/> Tomatoes</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="color: white;">
                                    Or Select from one of our speciality pizza
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="custom" value="Hawiian" onclick="addType()" /> Hawiian</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="custom" value="Veggie" onclick="addType()" /> Veggie</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="custom" value="MeatLovers" onclick="addType()" /> Meat Lovers</td>
                            </tr>                               
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br /><br />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="yumCookies()" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" onclick="clearDisplay()" /></td>                             
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="rightSidebar" class="shoppingCart">                    
                <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
                <div id="messages"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Can you perhaps narrow this down to a (much) smaller use case?  I understand that you posted your assignment in the question, but there's no way that all of that code is necessary to recreate your problem or to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropgation()` and `return false` for this purpose. And also return `yumCookies()` with `onclick()` event something like

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return yumCookies(event)" />
```

**javaScript**

```
function yumCookies(event){
    var pizzaSize = order[0];
    var pizzaCrust = order[1];
    var pizzaType = order[2];
    if (validateRadio() == false){
        alert("Please make your pizza choice selections and try again");    
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
   .......
   .......
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfppZ/1/)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I found you are very new to here, If you found the answer as you wanted then you can accept this answer, how to accept answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.